# Connection issue when trying to insert bulk record

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

We have a Spring Boot reactive application in our project and use HikariCP as the connection pool.

We sometimes are getting connection not available issue when trying to insert bulk records in DB.

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException:  - Connection is not available, request timed out after 4000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:?]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.trySchedule(MonoSubscribeOn.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoSubscribeOn.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:67) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4399) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.lambda$null$6(ReactorSleuth.java:312) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

inputFlux contains the records from JSON request to insert.

DAO call

```java
public Mono<Void> insertData(final Flux<Record> inputFlux) {

    return inputFlux.flatMap(record -> {
            return beginUpdate(dataSource, 
      sqlStatementSharedAbove).withStatementEnricher(stmt -> {
                stmt.setString(1, record.getFirstName());
                stmt.setString(2, record.getLastName());
                stmt.setInt(3, record.getAddress());
            }).build().doOnSuccess(affectedRows -> LOGGER.info("Added rows{}", affectedRows));

        }).then;
    }
```

DB parameter are set to:
max pool size - 60
conn timeout - 40000

The issue is occurring intermittently , say out of 5 runs one will fail with connection timeout.

Comment: Either you need more connections concurrently than the pool allows, or you're leaking connections, or possibly you're database server disallows creating as many connections as you need. Without a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace that is hard to say.

Comment: how to check if connections are leaking ? or
possibly you're database server disallows creating ? 
added stacktrace

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can i use inputFlux.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(400)).flatmap(..) to delay the consumption (DB insert )of the incoming traffic from handler. i tried this and it takes one connection per element and it seems sequential?